# So many /_ah/warmup requests

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web

My GAE application is hosted at [tickets-waiter.appspot.com](http://tickets-waiter.appspot.com/). It worked fine till some time. Now it calls `/_ah/warmup` requests more than 10 times during 2 hours.

```
I 2015-10-14 10:01:42.095  200       0 B  2.86 s I 10:01:44.745 I 10:01:44.752 I 10:01:44.942 I 10:01:44.942 I 10:01:44.946 I 10:01:44.958 /_ah/warmup
  0.1.0.3 - - [14/Oct/2015:00:01:42 -0700] "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 200 - - "-" "1.tickets-waiter.appspot.com" ms=2862 cpu_ms=3116 cpm_usd=0 instance=00c61b117c4a8572ec8f45546a378602d772d7 app_engine_release=1.9.27 trace_id=-
I 10:01:44.745 com.lana.ticket.LoadOnStartupServlet init: ! start
I 10:01:44.942 com.lana.ticket.LoadOnStartupServlet init: Stations dictonary with 18413 stations loaded successfully.
I 10:01:44.942 com.lana.ticket.LoadOnStartupServlet init: ! finish
I 10:01:44.946 com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.WarmupServlet service: Executing warm-up request.
I 10:01:44.958 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
I 2015-10-14 10:02:29.915  200       0 B  2.67 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:02:45.158  200       0 B   2.6 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:03:04.455  200       0 B  2.72 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:10:02.332  200       0 B  2.82 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:10:24.146  200       0 B     3 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:10:27.229  200       0 B  2.89 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:17:09.938  200       0 B  2.42 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:23:06.972  200       0 B   2.5 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:33:57.736  200       0 B  2.79 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:36:06.494  200       0 B  2.55 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:41:58.852  200       0 B  2.72 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:49:04.386  200       0 B  2.66 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:50:01.784  200       0 B  2.82 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 10:57:40.371  200       0 B   2.5 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 11:02:03.471  200       0 B  2.78 s /_ah/warmup
I 2015-10-14 11:07:01.651  200       0 B  2.52 s /_ah/warmup
```

GAE always creates new instances of my application. Can anyone explain why it happens?

Here are some graphs that show request and latency.

[Requests and latency graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ermNy.jpg)

My scaling options from appengine-web.xml:

```
<automatic-scaling>
    <min-idle-instances>5</min-idle-instances>
    <max-idle-instances>automatic</max-idle-instances>
    <min-pending-latency>automatic</min-pending-latency>
    <max-pending-latency>30ms</max-pending-latency>
    <max-concurrent-requests>50</max-concurrent-requests>
</automatic-scaling>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: post your app.yaml and maybe the graph that shows incoming request and latency from your Developer Console. We need more information to be able to answer this :)

Comment: @Patrice, I don't use `app.yaml`, I configure my application through `web.xml` and `appengine-web.xml`. Concerning the graphs - I have added them.

Comment: Fair enough. Could you post your scaling options then? If I'm right, they are in appengine-web.xml (I should've noticed the java tag, my bad)

Comment: @Patrice, I have posted my scaling options. I want to say that I don't change this settings and use the default ones.

Comment: Hmmmm I notice a couple of things : you have 5 instances currently, which is to be expected (you have minimum 5 idle, so it has to keep at LEAST that). Also, all your instances run pretty close to max memory. It's possible the system routinely "flushes" your instances to free memory, and being forced to keep 5 instances up, that makes a lot of restarts.

Comment: I get the same issue running `node` (express) on GAE.  It appears to be an infinite cycle of 302 / 307 redirects between https and http.  It appears independent of whether or not `secure: always` is enabled.  Any idea what's causing this?